# What is the difference betweel list & arraylist in android

Tags: android

Difference between  list & arraylist in android.
How can i sort out arraylist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list is an interface and ArrayList is an implementation of the List interface. The ArrayList class has only a few methods in addition to the methods available in the List interface.

Comment: Thanks Deepak . this will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

which list are we talking about?  Singly-linked list or doubly-linked(circular)-linked list?
One of the most obvious answers would be the access time.

For those links, accesstime would be O(n), while, arrayList being the nature of an array, the access-time is obviously O(1).

Comment: Sorry, i read the question too quickily, didn't see it for Android only.

Comment: ya I ask this question for interview perpose. Sorry for that But plz open my account